# Why can't I access my samba share via mDNS (bonjour)

Tags: windows, samba, mdns

I bought a cute little NAS box (MyBookWorld) that runs a samba server.  It's also got a mDNS server on it, and I've got bonjour installed on my windows box, so i can say  `ping orm.local` and it looks up the IP address just fine.  I can open up `\\192.168.1.6\` in explorer and that works just fine, but if I try to go to `\\orm.local\`  I get "the network path was not found".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it didn't work was that the mdns resolver was returning an auto-configured ipv6 address,  but the samba server didn't support ipv6.   Disabling ipv6 on the interface fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try to do some work from command promt:

1. ping by IP and host name
2. ns lookup by host name
3. check DNS settings on the box, computer and router
4. from the computer: command promt: msconfig /flushdns